# Show/Hide Elements with multiple attributes by attribute selection (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I try to find an easy solution (I am a totally coding beginner, just use javascript in widgets of a "out of the box" page) for the following problem:

There are multiple attributes visitor can select by click Remove/Show

- attribute a (Remove/Show)
- attribute b (Remove/Show)
- attribute c (Remove/Show)
- a.s.o.

based on visitors "selection", I would like to show or hide the list of elements:

- element 1 (attribute a and b) - Remove if "a" OR "b" has been selected
- element 2 (attribute a) - remove if "a" has been selected
- element 3 (attribute a and c) - remove, if "a" OR "c" has been selected
- a.s.o.

I am able already to hide elements based on a "selection", but in my solution every element show and hide only based on the unique ID (and so also only on the single selection).

The Javascript I found for that is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function swap(openlink,closelink, linkid, dataid)
{
if( document.getElementById(dataid).style.display == 'none')
{
document.getElementById(dataid).style.display='inline';
document.getElementById(linkid).firstChild.nodeValue=closelink;
} else
{
document.getElementById(dataid).style.display='none';
document.getElementById(linkid).firstChild.nodeValue=openlink;
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

And than I could use this HTML Code to Remove/Show the elements:

```
attribute a <a href="#swap" onclick="javascript:swap('Show','Remove', 'swaplinkA', 'showmeA')" id="swaplinkA" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkA">Remove</a>
attribute b <a href="#swap" onclick="javascript:swap('Show','Remove', 'swaplinkB', 'showmeB')" id="swaplinkB" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkB">Remove</a>
attribute c <a href="#swap" onclick="javascript:swap('Show','Remove', 'swaplinkC', 'showmeC')" id="swaplinkC" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkC">Remove</a>
```

And my element will be Remove/Show by this:

```
<div id="showmeA" style="display:inline">Element 1</div>
<div id="showmeB" style="display:inline">Element 2</div>
<div id="showmeB" style="display:inline">Element 3</div>
```

Is there an easy way to add 2 ids to one "element", so that for example Element 1 could be hidden by id=showmeA AND id=showmeB?

Comment: ids should be unique

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs. To add multiple classes to an element, just separate them with a space, e.g. `<div class="class-1 class-2 class-infinity">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said the issue yourself: **IDs are unique**.

This is exactly why you should use something else than `id`, and `class` attribute is perfectly fine as it does not have to be unique.

Then, this means that the function will not look for your elements using `getElementById()` but `getElementsByClassName()`.

Note that this function get element**s**, this involves that you have to loop through these element**s** and hide / show the ones targeted.

```
function swap(openlink, closelink, linkid, dataclass) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(dataclass);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if(element.style.display == 'none') {
            element.style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById(linkid).firstChild.nodeValue=closelink;
        } else {
            element.style.display='none';
            document.getElementById(linkid).firstChild.nodeValue=openlink;
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to replace id by class attributes to your HTML, you can put in as much as you want, they simply must be separated by a space:

```
<div class="showmeA showmeB">Element 1</div>
<div class="showmeB">Element 2</div>
<div class="showmeC">Element 3</div>
```

Here is an example that you can use to better understand the function and attributes used in your solution, this solves your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/sy2mxscf/

It is also important to inform you that [inline Javascript is bad](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/), you should reconsider your code when your Javascript skill will increase.

---

In order to solve the issue pointed out in the comments, you have to use some kind of counter and increment it when you hide the element, decrement it when you show element of one of his class, and displaying the associate element when this counter is 0.

This is also why you need two differentiated links: the "Remove" to increment, and the "Show" to decrement.

There are several way to implement this solution:

- Use an associative array in Javascript
- Use a custom attribute on the element
- Add and remove specific classes

I chose the last one but this may be not the best one, this is just one of the possibilities.

https://jsfiddle.net/sy2mxscf/2/

The idea is to add or remove a custom "hidemeX" class. If you click on two different "Remove" links targeting the same element, two classes will be added. If you then click on any "Show" link, the associate class will be removed. But there is still a "hidemeX" class remaining until you click on the second link, so the element is not displayed thanks to CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you guys are my heros! It works perfect! And I apprechiate a lot, that you have been able to explain it in a way that even I was able to understand! Perfect! If anyone of you come over to Shanghai, give me a note, I own you a beer!

Comment: @Steven I'm glad I could help a nice guy!

Comment: I have a problem with that I could not solve... sorry for asking stupid questions, I am afraid.

Comment: It works well to filter out for example all elements with attribute A, show A, than filter out B, than show B, filter out C. But when I try to combine them it will not work any more. For example Element 1 has attribute A & B & C. Filter one by one, the element will disapear and come back. But if I filter A by A, than also by B or C, the element will come back, if the attribute is not at the first position. I tried many changes, but I am too "new" to find how to "loop" it correct.. or however skilled guys would solve it... And advise?

Comment: @Steven I updated my answer to provide a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Delgan says, its better to use `class` here, and you can use those `<a>`'s id as their class, so when you use your function `swap`, you can easily trace back to decide if the elements is selected, so the div should be removed.

Below is how you can separate javascript logic and html structure.

```js
var swap = function(e) {
    var close = 'Remove', open = 'Show';
    var next = this.text === close ? open : close;
    // Set the clicked <a>'s text.
    this.text = next;
  
    // Get divs that will affect by this <a>
    var affectTarget = this.id;
    
    // Affected div elements
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName(affectTarget); 
    var i, len = targets.length;
    var visible;
    
    var watch, wLen, j;
     
    // For each <div> that will be affect by the clicked <a>, we have to chec :
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        // Get the classes that used as a list to show which <a> will have a effect on it.
        watch = targets[i].classList;
        wLen = watch.length;
        // visibilty is default to inline, if no <a> that it watches is selected, then it'll show
        visible = "inline";
        for (j = 0; j < wLen; ++j) {
            // If any of the <a> it watches is selected, set the visibilty to none.
            if (document.getElementById(watch[j]).text === open) {
                visible = "none";
                break;
            }
        }
        targets[i].style.display  = visible;
    }
};

// For each switcher, we register a click event for it.
var switchers = document.querySelectorAll("a.showSwitcher");
var i, len = switchers.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    switchers[i].addEventListener('click', swap);
}
```

```html
attribute a <a href="#swap"  class="showSwitcher" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkA" id="swaplinkA">Remove</a>
attribute b <a href="#swap"  class="showSwitcher" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkB" id="swaplinkB">Remove</a>
attribute c <a href="#swap"  class="showSwitcher" onfocus="this.blur()" name="swaplinkC" id="swaplinkC">Remove</a>

<hr/>

<div class="swaplinkA swaplinkB" style="display:inline">Element 1</div>
<div class="swaplinkA"style="display:inline">Element 2</div>
<div class="swaplinkA swaplinkC"style="display:inline">Element 3</div>
```

Comment: I also played around with that code a lot, but unfortunately not have been able to make him "running"... never got the effect, that a Element has been gone yet... I am sure for all skilled guys it`s obviously, but I did not found the point for days now.... sorry for bother you with my request. What I have to change to make it workable?

Comment: Open the dev-tool first, check if there's any error pop out when page loaded, or clicking on the links.